# Appstore navigation bar functionality

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, app-store, uinavigationbar, ios11

I wanted to implement a feature that is present in the Appstore app in iOS 11. As is visible from the gif, when the detail screen loads, the navigation bar is fully transparent and becomes visible when the view scrolls to the top.

[image]

I was under the impression that the navigation bar cannot be completely transparent. 
Any insights so as to how Apple has implemented this feature would be helpful/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Customizing the Navigation Bar section of this page.
Change the navigation background image and hide navigation bar on push

Also set [prefersLargeTitles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles?changes=latest_minor#see-also) of bar as true only in iOS 11